# How to create custom setup project in .Net?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, setup-project

I want to create custom setup for my c# project, as I understood I can not do it with Visual Studio Tools.
Here are the steps what I want to do during installation of my setup project:

- Install.Net Framework if not installed;
- Install Sql Server Express if not installed;
- Create Instance of Sql Server;
- Attache .mdf and .ldf to created instance of sql server;
- Install my software;

Does some one experience doing such kind of setup?
Please provide tools which you have used in your setup project.
If possible some working examples.
I heard about Setup Factory and Inno Setup. What do you think about them.
I strongly believe that somebody had done it before, please share with your experience!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Inno Setup:

**Inno Setup** (http://www.jrsoftware.org/) is very powerful open source installation system which is capable of doing all the steps you mentioned and it is pretty easy to learn.

Inno is using simple script format (similar to INI files) and Pascal language for writing advanced scripts.

As Inno is wide spread there are many resources and tutorials available online, e.g: [Inno Setup Extensions Knowledge Base](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Main_Page) , there is huge community, many examples in installation package, and really good help and manuals.

I cannot provide you complete script, but it is easy to find many of your tasks (quick shoot from SO):

[Inno Setup: Verify that .NET 4.0 is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104011/innosetup-how-to-check-the-framework-4-0)

[Unattended Install of SQL Server 2005 Express with LOCAL Server InstanceName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883631/unattended-install-of-sql-server-2005-express-with-local-server-instancename)

( A little of self promo here: )

If you want to create Inno installers directly from Visual Studio (2005/2008/2010/2012) you can use my (commercial) tool called Visual & Installer - http://www.unsigned-softworks.sk/visual-installer/index.html